# jQuery Validate - display field errors in tooltip plus "Please fill required fields" message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have custom ErrorPlacement function in my validator, which displays error in tooltip:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    var lastError = $(element).data('lastError'),
        newError = $(error).text();
    $(element).data('lastError', newError);
    if (newError !== '' && newError !== lastError) {
        $(element).tooltipster('content', newError);
        $(element).tooltipster('show');
    }
},
```

This works fine, but I would also need to display "Please, fill in all required fields" message on top of the form.

How can I do that with jQuery Validate?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bad english, You can use bootstrap tooltip for this like that
`

```
   rules: {
        first_name:"required",
    },

    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
        $(element).attr('data-original-title','');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        element.attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
        element.attr("data-original-title", error[0].innerHTML);
        error.css({
            'color': '#FF0000',
        });
        $('.is-invalid').tooltip();
        return false;
    },
    messages:{
      first_name:"Please provide first Name."
   }`
```

In error placement you define and initialize tooltip then in unhighlight you reset tooltip title.

Answer (score 0):

The option you are looking for is described in the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), under `errorContainer`:

> **errorContainer**
>   Hide and show this container when
>   validating. Example: Uses an additonal container for error messages.
>   The elements given as the errorContainer are all shown and hidden when
>   errors occur. However, the error labels themselves are added to the
>   element(s) given as errorLabelContainer, here an unordered list.
>   Therefore the error labels are also wrapped into li elements (wrapper
>   option).

Code would look like this:

```
$('form').validate({
    errorContainer:'#myErrorDiv'
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/3cDY4/